# jsp page javabean dialog box

Tags: javascript, jsp, javabeans

I have this:

```
<% if (nameBean.getTxnType().equalsIgnoreCase("Update"))
   { %>
    <TD><B>Gender: </B></TD>
    <TD><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="tbGender" 
               VALUE="<%= nameBean.getGender()%>" MAXLENGTH=1 SIZE=3 ></TD>
<% if (nameBean.getGender() == nameBean.setGender())
{ %>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
alert("Alert Box"); 
</script> 

<% } %>
```

How can I compare setgender's value to textbox's new gender value and have a dialog box that says gender already exits do you want modify to different one (Y/N) and do the necessary task. How can I make jsp value talk with JavaScript? How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JavaScript. You need to look into JSLT and pass beans so that you can read them by using ${object.Property} notation. This notation will allow you to use for-each loops, conditional statements etc.

Your (nameBean.getGender() == nameBean.setGender() doesn't make sense as getGender() returns true/false and setGender() is a mutator, hence it doesn't return anything.